# Ruby vs Perl in network programming

Tags: ruby, perl, network-programming

Whats the difference between Ruby and Perl when it comes to networking. Which is better to use and why?

Comment: If you already know one, but not the other, use the one you know. If you know neither, choose a different language that you do know. If you know both, you should be able to answer this question yourself.

Comment: I want to learn one of this language and trying to find out which is better. Network programming is kinda important for me so i am trying to decide based on that.

Comment: Perl is better designed for text processing and hard for later support and big projects. Ruby is rather universal and better for fast developing. Your question seems to be related to fast developing, so...

Comment: Networking is pretty minor in the grand scheme of things - try out both languages and see which you like better.

Comment: What boat is better for floating?

Comment: @mikerobi, *...for floating through ice.* *... for floating in mountains.* I don't see a problem to make answers here.

Comment: Sad... question was closed not because it's impossible to answer it, but because it's possible, but potential answerer was not so fast, as active closers ) I mean, I think it's possible to make a full argumented nice answer, but question should be closed because holywars and bad answers would be much more popular.

Comment: @Nakilon - YOU may be a poor software developer and thus can't develope well designed Perl code. That's not Perl's fault. My systems in Perl are easy for later support, are large projects and I develop fast.

Comment: OMG, just like I said... good quality can exist, but it will not... sad.

Comment: Note: Nakilon's first comment is a load of rubbish.

Comment: Nakilon's comment reminds me of http://www.defectiveperlprogramming.com/?p=107

Comment: I think this is a really good question. it is only potential answers that are the problem

Comment: @justintime, exactly. It's good, but not for a broad audience. Too risky. We can now see it in comments.

Comment: @DVK, a hero, read this http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/nobody-cares-what-your-code-looks-like.html

Comment: @justintime - the problem is not the question. It's the fact that such questions bring out a lot less thoughtful fact based answers and a lot more "I can't feel good about MY languages of choice without baselessly bashing someone else's", like Nakilon's comment above.

Comment: What a marasm are you talking... 42 years old, but looks like nervous scholar. Shame on you, troll.

Comment: @Nakilon: Later Max learned about Moose and other modern Perl features and decided that Perl is still better.

Comment: @Nakilon: I read the codinghorror blog. So what? If you read the comments also, there's a differing opinion. And Max changed his mind: http://use.perl.org/~chromatic/journal/33191

Comment: @runrig - that link is 404 now but I believe you meant to link to Max's blog post he made later called "Ooh I made Coding Horror", and was a rebuttal of sorts to BOTH his original assessment of Perl's suitability and to Jeff's blog. http://avatraxiom.livejournal.com/70947.html

Comment: @Nakilon - specifically, to quote from Max's follow-up post: **"Since the "problems of Perl" post, I've had the opportunity to start a brand-new project in Perl ... also because I wanted to see if using all the modern techniques of Perl development could lead to well-architected code from the start...** ... (to be continued in next commen)

Comment: ... ***I found that Moose is the best object system in any language I've ever used***. I find it weird that when I go to write in other languages again, I'll probably think, "Gee, I wish this had Moose." I used to think, "I'm so glad this language isn't Perl" (except when dealing with regular expressions, which are so much easier to use in Perl than in other languages). But with Moose, I just wish everything had Moose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both languages are very similar and if you're just starting out then Ruby is probably easier to learn than Perl.

But if have a specific area you are targeting, then it probably comes down to which has the better libraries in that area. And in questions about breadth and quality of libraries, Perl wins almost all battles because of the [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org). Take a few minutes and search for the types of libraries you're interested in and compare that with what you'll find on [Ruby Gems](http://rubygems.org/)